# Scraping href in div elements with python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

My code is working but it just writes `all done` to the output. I debugged but didn't understand anything. I just want to get the link of each element in the table where I put the `screenshot`. How can I do ?

My code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

USER_AGENT = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:95.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/95.0'}

line = "football"


def search():
    apk_mirror_url = f'https://www.apkmirror.com/?post_type=app_release&searchtype=apk&s={line}'
    response = requests.get(apk_mirror_url, headers=USER_AGENT).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
    for link in soup.find_all("div", {'class': 'accent_color'}):
        raw_url = link.get('href')
        print(raw_url)
    print("all done!")


search()
```

ScreenShots:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZ0Wi.png)

Comment: You are not returning anything, is that correct...?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `<div>` with these `class` - So try to select your elements more specific:

```
for link in soup.find_all("div", {'class': 'appRowVariantTag wrapText'}):
    raw_url = link.a.get('href')
```

or alternative with `css selector`:

```
for link in soup.select('.appRowVariantTag.wrapText a'):
    raw_url = link.get('href')
```

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

USER_AGENT = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:95.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/95.0'}

line = "football"


def search():
    apk_mirror_url = f'https://www.apkmirror.com/?post_type=app_release&searchtype=apk&s={line}'
    response = requests.get(apk_mirror_url, headers=USER_AGENT).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
    for link in soup.select('.appRowVariantTag.wrapText a'):
        raw_url = link.get('href')
        print(raw_url)
    print("all done!")
search()
```

##### Output

```
/apk/gameloft/real-football/real-football-1-7-3-release/
/apk/miniclip-com/soccer-stars/soccer-stars-34-0-0-release/
/apk/nfl-enterprises-llc/nfl-fantasy-football/nfl-fantasy-football-3-57-8-release/
/apk/nfl-enterprises-llc/nfl-fantasy-football/nfl-fantasy-football-3-57-7-release/
/apk/nfl-enterprises-llc/nfl-fantasy-football/nfl-fantasy-football-3-57-6-release/
all done!
```